# get custom query with nodejs sequelize with mysql

Tags: node.js, api, sequelize.js, backend

if this is my data

| name | code | qnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t | 2 | 4 |
| t | 2 | 5 |
| b | 3 | 3 |
| b | 3 | 2 |
| b | 3 | 7 |

I want to get data like this

| name | code | qnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| t | 2 | 4 |
| t | 2 | 5 |
| - | - | 9 |
| b | 3 | 3 |
| b | 3 | 2 |
| b | 3 | 7 |
| - | - | 12 |

I mean to get all rows and total of qnt of rows that have same name and code under rows.

I have to show a table in this format

Comment: I think you would be better off Making a standard request/a bunch of standard requests and then treating the problem as a normal js problem.

Comment: and how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `WITH ROLLUP` from MySQL and need to use the raw SQL query:

```js
const rows = await sequelize.query(`
SELECT name, code, qnt
FROM table
GROUP BY name WITH ROLLUP
`, {
  type: QueryTypes.SELECT
});
```

Comment: thanks but there is two problems, 1 there is no sum and whene i want to group by name and code the response is not what i want

Comment: Can you show the result in the updated post?